# can we make mp4 file web optimized without moving moov atom?

Tags: video, video-streaming, mp4, video-processing

I have to do transcode the mp4 file without changing the mp4 file structure so can I do that or not without moving moov atom?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t. Think of a moov like an index in a book. You can’t tell where in the book something will be before the book is written. At the end you can move the index to the front, but you can’t write it or even know it’s size beforehand.

Comment: Suppose I move the moov atom at the begining of the mp4 file then the hash of the my original file and the transcoded file's hash is changed. so Is there any other method to web optimizing the mp4 file?

Comment: “Web optimizing” is moving the moov to the front. So the question has become, can I move the moov without moving the moov.  And of corse the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. The MOOV atom can essentially be everywhere in the file. Typically, the file is downloaded from the first zero bytes onwards until the MOOV atom has been detected. From that moment, the video file can start playing provided that the mdat atoms for the first seconds of the video have been downloaded as well.

Here's a representation of the atoms in a web optimized MP4 video file:

[image: MOOV atom location]

Here's a MOOV atom location detector so you can see if it's optimized for web playback:

https://www.advalify.io/video-validator/video-moov-atom-position